# Calling Java Script function from SetTimeout in Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal

```
declare var  loadMobileFuncs: any;

    class Foo {
         ---
         async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
              setTimeout(async () => {
                    loadMobileFuncs();
              }, 10);
        }
      }
```

loadMobileFuncs is a java script function in a js file.

When I run it I get error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: loadMobileMenuFuncs is not defined ReferenceError: loadMobileFuncs is not defined at Timeout.

No error if running without Angular Universal. Code still works fine even in Angular Universal!  So why is the console showing this error ?

Comment: With the code you have shown, that error makes sense.  You've declared a variable called `loadMobileFuncs` and said it can be `any` type, but you have not assigned it a value.  So right now `loadMobileFuncs = undefined` since you have not defined a value.

Comment: This is how Angular calls JS function. As far as I know function needs to be declared as any .  If the  call is moved out of SetTimeout(),  there is no error

Comment: Where does that `loadMobileFuncs` come from?  I have search online and nothing comes up. This is part of Angular?

Comment: This is my own custom function and it's included  in the js folder

Comment: If that js is not loaded by universal it won't be available at runtime.

Comment: Where did u add this js file that has `loadMobileFuncs` ? index.html, angular.json or lazy load ?

Comment: js file was added in angular.json   Also if I make timeout to 80 from 10, all works fine even on 3G

Comment: Careful, the `angular.json` contains 2 sections. [`architect`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/angular.json#L39) and [`server`](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/blob/master/MintPlayer.Web/ClientApp/angular.json#L149)